# Accessing hash tables values in the same hash table in powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, hashtable

I'm storing a lot of variables that depend on other variables, that themselves depend on other variables, like so :

```
$soft_version = "5.8.2"
$soft_filename = "somesoft-${soft_version}.exe"
$soft_path = "/some/path/$soft_filename"
$soft_call_args = "/S /forcerestart"
```

And I'd like to store this in a hash table so that I can access the values more easily : so I tried the following

```
$soft = @{
version="5.8.2";
filename="somesoft-${soft.version}.exe"
path="/some/path/$soft.filename"
call_args = "/S /forcerestart"
}
```

So that I can access the values like this :

```
$soft.version
$soft.filename
$soft.path
$soft.call_args
```

But it doesn't seem to work, corresponding keys remain empty :

```
$soft

Name                           Value                                                                                               
----                           -----                                                                                               
filename                       somesoft-.exe
path                           /some/path/
call_args                      /S /forcerestart
version                        5.8.2
```

Is there a way I could access values of an hash table inside the same hash table ? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap in brackets, this works for me (PSVersion 5):

```
$soft = @{
version="5.8.2";
filename="somesoft-$($soft.version).exe"
path="/some/path/$($soft.filename)"
call_args = "/S /forcerestart"
}
```

**Result**

```
$soft

Name                           Value   
----                           -----
filename                       somesoft-5.8.2.exe
path                           /some/path/somesoft-5.8.2.exe
call_args                      /S /forcerestart
version                        5.8.2
```

Comment: It's not quite clear in my mind why it is needed to do so, but it also pointed out that I was using underscores (_) instead of points (.). Many thanks !

Comment: My bad, it doesn't work. You may have tried several times, which lead powershell to register the $soft.version value. Thus, when you refer to $($soft.version), powershell already has the whole $soft hash table in memory. I don't know if this is clear for you, but try to open a new ps session, copy paste your code and call $soft, you'll see. Thanks for trying though !

Comment: You are totally right, Adrien. Im pretty sure, PS does not support recursive declaration, because the value of a var isnt known, when assigned to another var.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the new v5 classes or custom objects

[PowerShell: Creating Custom Objects](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7804.powershell-creating-custom-objects.aspx)